# numpy array backed by shared memory: BufferError

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pointers, shared-memory

I'm running into an error in using `multiprocessing.shared_memory` to back a numpy array.
Here's my usage pattern:

```py
# demo.py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
from typing import Iterator
import numpy as np

@contextmanager
def allocate_shared_mem() -> Iterator[SharedMemory]:
    with SharedMemoryManager() as smm:
        shared_mem = smm.SharedMemory(size=80)
        yield shared_mem

with allocate_shared_mem() as shared_mem:
    shared_arr = np.frombuffer(shared_mem.buf)
    assert len(shared_arr) == 10
```

And here is the issue I'm seeing:

```
$ python demo.py
Exception ignored in: <function SharedMemory.__del__ at 0x7ff8bf604ee0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rig1/miniconda3/envs/pysc/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py", line 184, in __del__
  File "/home/rig1/miniconda3/envs/pysc/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py", line 227, in close
BufferError: cannot close exported pointers exist
```

I think the problem is that the `SharedMemoryManager` cannot deallocate `shared_mem` while the numpy array exists. If I append `del shared_array` to the end of the `with` block at the bottom of `demo.py`, the issue goes away.

How can I use numpy arrays backed by shared memory without having to manually account for array deletion? Are there any clean patterns or array-invalidation tricks to handle this case?

I'm worried that some other part of my code will grab a handle to the array and it will be a hassle to figure out what object should be deleted to avoid the "cannot close exported pointers exist" error. It's fine with me if the numpy array becomes invalid after the `with` block exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) does, you can use `numpy.ndarray` initializer directly to create an array with no buffer management.

```py
@contextmanager
def allocate_shared_mem() -> Iterator[SharedMemory]:
    with SharedMemoryManager() as smm:
        shared_mem = smm.SharedMemory(size=80)
        yield shared_mem


def run():
    with allocate_shared_mem() as shared_mem:
        shared_arr = np.ndarray((10,), dtype=np.float64, buffer=shared_mem.buf)
        shared_arr[:] = 1

    print(shared_arr)  # This should not work, but it does.


run()
```

Note that you can also export an array instead of a buffer.

```py
@contextmanager
def allocate_shared_mem() -> Iterator[SharedMemory]:
    with SharedMemoryManager() as smm:
        shared_mem = smm.SharedMemory(size=80)
        shared_arr = np.ndarray((10,), dtype=np.float64, buffer=shared_mem.buf)
        yield shared_arr


def run():
    with allocate_shared_mem() as shared_arr:
        shared_arr[:] = 1

    print(shared_arr)  # This will crash without raising any exception.


run()
```